# How do I create a pointcut to intercept all methods in a class with PostSharp?

Tags: postsharp

I've tried using AttributeTargetTypes, but it just won't work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to apply an aspect to all methods of a class is to annotate this class with the aspect custom attribute. AttributeTargetTypes, when the custom attribute is applied on assembly-level, should work also, at least if the type is a part of the current assembly.